# Cortex M0 vs M0+ Programming perspective

Tags: arm, cortex-m

I am struggling with which cortex to choose.
Currently I have a design guy that will give me an M0 with memory for initial development but I want to use M0+ eventually.
Assuming I give up the optional features of the M0+ (MPU and MTB), can I transfer the M0 code to the M0+ without any changes?

I mean, is it the same libraries? same build commands? Linker? 
What differences should I consider? I know they have the same ISA so I figured it shouldn't be a problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I'm planning on using the ARM compiler with command prompt via Windows 7 but suggestions are welcome (except using Linux, It's not my decision).

Comment: What level of hardware are we at here? Are we talking about literally changing _just_ the CPU core in the RTL of a silicon/FPGA design, or swapping one Cortex-M0-based MCU for another Cortex-M0+-based MCU in a board/system design?

Comment: The core is a small part of this, the peripherals and other chip items represent the bulk of the code.  If they are not compatible then it is a no-go (without an abstraction layer and chip specific underneath).

Comment: I haven't start anything yet. I'm waiting for a confirmation that both Cortexes are identical in code so I won't make double work.

Comment: if you want to compare the arm cores, then just read the arm documentation, it tells you.  they are both armv6-m yes?  and do any of the instructions vary beyond architecture, are there any that specify a subset of armv6-m?

Comment: the cores are by far the least of your problems though, only a small part of the chip, it is the differences in the rest of the chip that matter as far as porting code. 99.999999% of the code has nothing to do with the core in this case.  that is what you should be worried about, not m0 vs m0+.

Comment: you can compile for thumb using the armv4t original thumb and it works on every arm processor that has come after micro or full sized.  the instruction set is the least of your worries.

Comment: your question is like asking, I have a 1975 pickup with a chevy 350 engine, and I am thinking of switching to a 1985 sedan with a chevy 350 engine and want to know if I can use the same grille and front bumper on both, or do I have to get a different grille and bumper.  How would I figure this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just consider M0 versus M0+ and not the system peripherals, all code compiled for Cortex-M0 should work on a Cortex-M0+ platform. They use the same instruction set and programmer model.

The main differences are about MPU and MTB, but also the fact that Cortex-M0 has no User-mode support (All code runs in privileged, ie `CONTROL.nPRIV` cannot be 1).

Comment: That's actually the answer I was looking for. 
Thanks!